# Ninject bindings 101

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Newbie Ninject question klaxxon.

I have the following classes and interfaces which describe a dependency I need to inject, and a depender into which a concrete instance of the dependency needs to be injected.

```
public interface IDependency { }

public class FooDependency : IDependency { }

public class Depender
{
    [Inject]
    public IDependency Dependency { get; set; }

    public bool DependencyIsNull()
    {
        return Dependency == null;
    }
}
```

I have setup my bindings with a NinjectModule instance, like so.

```
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IDependency>().To<FooDependency>();
    }
}
```

And here's a unit test method which asserts that the dependency has been injected into the depender.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
   var kernel = new StandardKernel(new Bindings());
   var bar = new Depender();
   Assert.IsFalse(bar.DependencyIsNull());
}
```

I'm clearly doing something fundamentally wrong, as I would have expected the test to pass, but it doesn't.

Comment: So, what did you expect? That Ninject magically hooks into the .NET runtime and intercepts the creation of objects and notices that you created a new object and injected stuff into this? IoC containers are not magical unicorns. They force you to write your code in a specific way: let the container/kernel build up a graph of objects and request the root object from the container/kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object isn't created by your `kernel`. Everything needs to be created by the `kernel` to have dependencies injected:

```
// option a (recommended)
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new Bindings());
var bar = kernel.Get<IDependency>();
Assert.IsFalse(bar.DependencyIsNull());

// option b (not recommended.. but do-able)
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new Bindings());
var bar = new Depender();
kernel.Inject(bar); // injects after the fact
Assert.IsFalse(bar.DependencyIsNull());
```

Also, you should have that `DependencyIsNull` method in your interface:

```
public interface IDependency {
    bool DependencyIsNull();
}
```

Comment: If the interface represents the depedency itself why would it have a method to say it is null. It's like having a method AmINull() in the object class. If it is null you don't have a instance to call the method.

Comment: It would appear it was badly named. `IDependency` in this instance would be `bar`.. which is of type `FooDependency` in the OP's bindings... which is a concrete class that checks its own dependencies for `null`. Its confusing obviously since the types are named incorrectly.